# Pass Inputs to Function to get Predictions

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cloudera

I am trying to deploy a model via a REST API function (new to it) to apply predictions to unlabeled data on the fly.
I do not understand how to map my input features to the args (or maybe it should be kwargs) function

Using this simple example as a guide

```
# Read the fitted model from the file model.pkl
# and define a function that uses the model to
# predict petal width from petal length

import pickle
import numpy as np

model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

def predict(args):
  iris_x = np.reshape(float(args.get('petal_length')), (-1,1))
  result = model.predict(iris_x)
  return result[0][0]

predict({'petal_length': 3})
0.88346654397265678

# doing it manually via dataframe

row = {'petal_length': 3}
df = pd.DataFrame([row])
result = model.predict(df)
result[0][0]
0.88346654397265678
```

I have a dataframe as input with 13 features with mixed data types that are plugged into a sklearn classification pipeline performing FE techniques like scaling, ohe, and tfidf ... the api function does not work and looks like something to do with the shape based on the error ... it seems the input format has to be a dataframe because of the sklearn pipeline

```
model = joblib.load(persisted_model)

def preds(args):
  unlabeled_X = np.reshape(args\
                 .get('c1',\
                     'c2',\
                     'c3',\
                     'c4',\
                     'c5',\
                     'c6',\
                     'c7',\
                     'c8',\
                     'c9',\
                     'c10',\
                     'c11',\
                     'c12',\
                     'c13'), (-1,13))
  result = model.predict(unlabeled_X)
  return result[0][0]

# using dummy data as example
preds({
  "c1": "some text",
  "c2": "more text",
  "c3": 0,
  "c4": 0,
  "c5": 0,
  "c6": "cat var",
  "c7": "cat var",
  "c8": "cat var",
  "c9": "flag",
  "c10": 0,
  "c11": 0,
  "c12": 0,
  "c13": 0
})

TypeError: get expected at most 2 arguments, got 13
```

If I try the manual approach via dict to df it works

```
# using dummy data as example
row = {
  "c1": "some text",
  "c2": "more text",
  "c3": 0,
  "c4": 0,
  "c5": 0,
  "c6": "cat var",
  "c7": "cat var",
  "c8": "cat var",
  "c9": "flag",
  "c10": 0,
  "c11": 0,
  "c12": 0,
  "c13": 0
}

df = pd.DataFrame([row])
model.predict(df)[0]
'CLASS1'
```

My main question is how do I get the api function to work so it can accept new data to make predictions?

Perhaps the function can be modified to transform the dictionary input to a dataframe so the API can be called?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a hint of a REST service here. Are you sure you're after REST API?

Comment: the documentation refers to it as rest api / rest endpoint https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/data-science-workbench/latest/topics/cdsw_models.html